# Is it OK to use glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS) all the time?

Tags: opengl

I wonder if it is OK to always use glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS)?
Or is it better to push only the bits necessary due to some performance issues?

Comment: It's better to, as datenwolf pointed out, to not use deprecated features.

Answer (score 7):

The attrib stack has been removed from modern OpenGL versions, so I'd rather not use it in new code. It's depreciation is IMHO incentive enough not to use it regardless of any performance concerns.

Answer (score 4):

(Like other users pointed out - it is generally better to avoid deprecated features, however the rest of this answer assumes you need to stick with it for some reason)

There is no simple answer for this, because performance difference (if any) would depend on GPU, driver implementation, number of push/pops in your program and possibly other factors. Testing would be required, but remember that just because there might be no difference on your configuration and with your current code, it might be quite different on other configurations or in the future when your code grows. Personally, I would recommend you only push bits you actually need to save if you are worried about performance.

Edit: I did a quick test on Radeon 5870 with 13.4 drivers, using GPU PerfStudio to check CPU time of calls. It seems GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS takes about 30-40 microseconds to push (and about the same to pop), other bits vary between 1-8. So there is a difference and also, compared to other calls, 30-40 us is quite a bit of time - in my program only glClear and some glDrawArrays took more then this.

Comment: if you want to measure the cost of Push/Pop, you also need to check how much more time the following Draw takes (as GL state has been changed, and might require more validation at draw time). That, and also the _GPU_ time required to apply all those state changes.